# Making data from one schema available to another schema

Tags: replication, oracle-11g-r2, table

I need to make data that is currently in one schema available to a different user in the same Oracle database.  Does this require that we replicate data from one schema to another?  Or is there a simpler approach?

Comment: Are they in the same database? If so, just use grants and a synonym on a single table. Way easier

Comment: Yes table to be replicated will be in the same database. Could you please explain this process with an example

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but if you don't understand my previous comment (how to implement), you really shouldn't be doing this at all.

Comment: @polle - That completely changes the question that you're asking.  I've rewritten the question based on the new information, please verify that our new understanding is correct.

Comment: Good job @JustinCave. +1 for your answer

Answer (score 4):

If the table is in a single database, you don't want to replicate it.  You don't want to create a second copy of the data.  You simply want to give access to whatever schemas need access to the data.  You may also want to create some synonyms so that you don't have to use fully qualified names.

If `userA` owns `table1` and you want that data to be visible to `userB`

```
SQL> grant select on userA.table1 to userB
```

If you want `userB` to be able to refer to the table as `table1` rather than `userA.table1`

```
SQL> create public synonym table1 for userA.table1
```